# Screen flickering after changing to custom refresh rate

Tags: laptop, display, lenovo-laptop, laptop-display, refresh-rate

I have a Lenovo Legion 5 Pro 16ACH6H, that automatically offers refresh rates of 60 Hz and 165 Hz.

I thought I could also change to 100 Hz (to save battery etc.). In Linux I created a custom profile using `xrandr --newprofile` and changed to 100 Hz. After that, the screen was flickering between a blackscreen and the correct screen and didn't stop when I changed back to 60 Hz. It happens everywhere, in Linux, Windows and even in BIO

[1/4 slow motion video in GRUB](https://streamable.com/aayh3e)

Now if I change between custom refresh rates, the flickering gets "stronger" (longer black time or lower Hz) when using lower refresh rates and gets "lower" at higher refreh rates.

Over some hours, the flickering gets lesser and lesser. Now the weirdest part: When I change to 165 Hz, the flickering is gone, but there are strange lines over the display and the image is "burning" into the screen (I see shadows of the windows, when I move them). When I change back to any other refresh rate then, the flickering restart with the whole intensity and the burnt images are still there visible as shadows.

The 165 Hz thing only happens when I'm the "dynamic mode", that means, that the AMD GPU is used (Internal GPU of Ryzen 7 5800H, driver amdgpu). This doesn't happen in "discrete mode" where the NVIDIA GPU is used.

The "shadow images" are still there when I reboot or leave the laptop shut down for some days, so they may be written to some non-volatile storage or to some storage that is kept alive. I already removed the battery and the CMOS battery for a night, but the flickering didn't disappear.

It's not important for me how to get the 100 Hz work, but to have a method to stop the flickering.

Comment: You could try turning it off and disconnecting the battery for a while. If there is a CMOS backup you’d probably need to remove that as well

Comment: @JamesP This didn't work unfortunately